# Preconfigure FTP servers in FTPCafe android app

Tags: android, ftp

I need to install FTP cafe many times on multiple devices and configure the ftp servers manually each time i install the app. If there could be a way to pre-configure the servers, it would be very helpful. I install FTPcafe app using the adb install command.

I have root permissions in the device, have some experience with the commands : adb install, adb push/ pull, adb shell.

**My approach to the solution**

If i know the path of file where server details are stored which the app uses to fetch the info, then i can copy that file to my laptop and at each installation, i can just simply adb push the file. So, the app will fetch the server details without having to re-enter them.

Somehow, i managed to find out that **/data/data/com.ftpcafe.trial/shared_prefs/** is the path where server profiles (as *.xml files) are stored. So, i setup the required servers on one device. Copied the entire folder **/data/data/com.ftpcafe.trial** to new device. But FTPcafe **doesn't** show any profiles on the GUI. The drop-down is **un-clickable**. 
I also asked the same on their [official forum](http://www.droidwareuk.com/smf/index.php?topic=1116.0) and support through email but couldn't get any clue. Any idea?

[FTPCafe Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftpcafe.trial&hl=en)

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: You have to reboot such a device before changes in shared_prefs show up.

Comment: You could also try to first put back the xml files and then install the app.

Comment: But then... What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @greenapps Thanks. I tried option 1 but no luck.. i will try option 2 and update here ASAP.